# Switch Case handling two different scenarios

Tags: swift

I have the following implementation where potentially I could able to get two different error types as `CustomError` and `ClassError`.

However if I receive a `ClassError`, it goes into switch statement of `CustomError`'s `default` case. I am wondering how to handle this scenario.

```
 switch completion {
    case .failure (let error):
      switch error as? CustomError {
      case .cFailed:
         // show alert here
      case .nFailed:
        // show alert here
      default:
       // show alert here
      }

      switch error as? ClassError {
      case .gFailed:
         // show alert here
      default:
        // show alert here
      }

    return
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a properly nested switch like this:

```
switch completion {
case .failure(let error as CustomError):
    switch error {
    case .cFailed:
        // show alert here
        break
    case .nFailed:
        // show alert here
        break
    default:
        // show alert here
        break
    }
case .failure(let error as ClassError):
    switch error {
    case .gFailed:
        print("ClassError.gFailed")
    default:
        // show alert here
        break
    }
default:
    break
}
```

Or else, you can write a single level switch:

```
switch completion {
case .failure(CustomError.cFailed):
    //...
    break
case .failure(CustomError.nFailed):
    //...
    break
case .failure(ClassError.gFailed):
    print("ClassError.gFailed")
default:
    break
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to cast error to desire type, example:

```
if let customError = error as? CustomError {
    // handle CustomError switch statement here
} else if classError = error as? ClassError {
    // handle ClassError switch statement here
}
```

Hope this solution will help you!

Answer (score 1):

```
let error: Error = CustomError.nFailed

switch error {
case CustomError.cFailed:
    print("cFailed")
case CustomError.nFailed:
    print("nFailed") // "nFailed\n"
case ClassError.gFailed:
    print("gFailed")
default:
    print("default")
}
```

Works fine !

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative, throw the error on the switch case and catch it outside, how 'bout dah?

```swift
do {
    switch result {
    case .success:
        print("WOO")
    case .failure(let error):
        throw error
    }
} catch CustomError.cFailed {
    print("cFailed")
} catch CustomError.nFailed {
    print("nFailed")
} catch ClassError.gFailed {
    print("gFailed")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```